# Python -- "Batch Processing" of multiple existing scripts

Tags: python, batch-file

I have written three simple scripts (which I will not post here, as they are part of my dissertation research) that are all in working order.

What I would like to do now is write a "batch-processing" script for them.  I have many (read as potentially tens of thousands) of data files on which I want these scripts to act.

My questions about this process are as follows:

1. What is the most efficient way to go about this sort of thing?
2. I am relatively new to programming.  Is there a simple way to do this, or is this a very complex endeavor?

Before anyone downvotes this question as "unresearched" or whatever negative connotation comes to mind, PLEASE just offer help.  I have spent days reading documentation and following leads from Google searches, and it would be most appreciated if a human being could offer some input.

Comment: How should the scripts be run?  First script on all files, second script on all files, third script on all files; or all three on first file, all three on second file, ... ?

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? If you mean time, then we'd have to know a lot more about what your scripts do and how they connect up and where and how they spend their time than just that they exist.

Comment: @EthanFurman, it really doesn't matter.  They are independent of one another, but at some point, all three of the scripts need to get run on all of the files.

Comment: @abarnert, What I mean by "most efficient" is the least amount of code to get the job done.  I have a little bit of luxury in that I can set the batch-processing to run, and just walk away for however long it takes.  If I'm looking at something that will take an hour to run instead of a few minutes, obviously that would be a consideration, but I'll worry about streamlining things later if need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to have the scripts run, probably a shell script would be the easiest thing.

If you want to stay in Python, the best way would be to have a `main()` (or somesuch) function in each script (and have each script importable), have the batch script import the subscript and then run its `main`.

If staying in Python:
  - your three scripts must have the `.py` ending to be importable
  - they should either be in Python's search path, or the batch control script can set the path
  - they should each have a `main` function (or whatever name you choose) that will activate that script

For example:

batch_script

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/location/of/subscripts')

import first_script
import second_script
import third_script

first_script.main('/location/of/files')
second_script.main('/location/of/files')
third_script.main('/location/of/files')
```

example sub_script

```
import os
import sys
import some_other_stuff
SOMETHING_IMPORTANT = 'a value'

def do_frobber(a_file):
   ...

def main(path_to_files):
    all_files = os.listdir(path_to_files)
    for file in all_files:
        do_frobber(os.path.join(path_to_files, file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

This way, your subscript can be run on its own, or called from the main script.

Comment: I'm needing to stay in Python.  What do you mean about having each script importable?  Is that something that must be done to a .py file?

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86: '.py' files are importable, but they also have to be accessible to Python (which means in the Python search path).  So the batch script needs to be able to say `import script1`* and have your first script available to it.  *'script1' should be your actual script name.

Comment: Is it necessary for the file I'm importing to be in the same directory as the batch processing file, or is it sufficient to specify the path?

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86 It should be ok to specify the path.

Comment: @TimB: The path cannot be specified in an `import`.

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86: Being in the same directory actually isn't relevant at all, because it's the current working directory, not the script directory, that matters. (Well, you can use `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))`, but the point is, you still need the `sys.path` munging.)

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86: Actually, another alternative is to put all of the scripts in a package together (a directory named `pkgname` with an `__init__.py` file), which means you run it with `python -m pkgname.main`; in that case, you can `from . import first_script`. (Or you can rename `main.py` to `__init__.py`, and then run it with `python -m pkgname`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a batch script in python using `os.walk()` to generate a list of the files and then process them one by one with your existing python programs.

```
import os, re

for root, dir, file in os.walk(/path/to/files):
    for f in file:
        if re.match('.*\.dat$', f):
            run_existing_script1 root + "/" file
            run_existing_script2 root + "/" file
```

If there are other files in the directory you might want to add a regex to ensure you only process the files you're interested in.

EDIT - added regular expression to ensure only files ending ".dat" are processed.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is a regex?

Comment: Regex is regular expression

Comment: @Palmetto_Girl86 - Sorry, a regex is a regular expression and is used to match string patterns. You can use them in python with the `re` module [(link)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I'll update my answer to include one as an example.